# Adding integrands together

Tags: integration

From what I understand, the condition to add two integrands together is absolute convergence.
Is there any example of integrals which are convergent but not absolute convergent for which this fails? meaning that,
$$\int f(x)+\int g(x)\neq\int\left[f(x)+g(x)\right]$$

Comment: $f=1$ and $g=-1$ on the real line.

Comment: But f is not convergent and not absolute convergent on an improper interval, and on a finite interval it is both.

Comment: If the integrals aren't absolutely convergent then the notation $\int f(x)$ is ambiguous; you need to pick a specific limit and the answer can depend on what limit you choose, e.g. $\lim_{\ell \to \infty} \int_{-\ell}^{\ell+x} f(t) \, dt$ may be a nontrivial function of $x$.